# CSS Nested Div with flex styling to achieve desirable scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following div :
[image]

I am trying to make the Form Content Scrollable while leaving everything else fixed. The dialog height changes based on the form content and can grow upto the window size. But beyond that it should add a scroll in the form content.

I tried playing around with flex and got it working IF THE TAB divs (Tab parent and tab content) were not present. Even then the scroll bar remains permanently even if the height is available (Another problem but not as major).

Any suggestions on how to use flex styling on the mutable divs to get the scrolling just on form content?

The CSS that worked when tab portion was not present:

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: flex;">
  <div id="form" style="display: flex; flex-direction: columnl">
    <div id="formContent" style="overflow-y: auto;"></div>
    <div id="formFooter"></div>  
  <div>
</div>
```

The above HTML and CSS worked as expected, adding a scrollbar to the form content. **BUT** when the dialog is maximum height, and the scroll bar is no longer required, the scroll bar is still present.

This approach does not work when the tab portion is included. It is creating unexpected behavior by showing 2 scrollbars or scrolling the entire dialog instead of just the form content. One for the form content div and another for dialog div.

The HTML CSS is as follows:

```
<div id="Dialog" style="height:300px;overflow-y: auto;width: 400px;">
  <div id="DialogContent">
    <div id="TabController">
      <div id="tabHeader">
      </div>
      <div id="tabContentPanel">
        <div id="tabContent">
          <div id="form">
            <div id="formContent">             
              Y U NO SCROLL ????
            </div>
            <div id="formFooter">
              This is the Footer.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please can you include your code (HTML and CSS) in the question.

Comment: Added. Adding further more code that includes the tab portion of the problem.

Comment: FYI, the `flex` tag refers to Apache Flex.  I changed it to `flexbox` as this is a CSS question.